# How to validate array input for array field using Sequelize.js and PostgreSQL?

Tags: arrays, node.js, postgresql, validation, sequelize.js

I'm using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) + [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) + [Sequelize.js 2.0.2](http://sequelizejs.com/). I have the following schema definition for the phone field which could be array of strings, but only number is allowed:

```
var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    ....
    ....
    /** Phone number
     * Multiple numbers should be registered due to
     */
    phone: {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            isNumeric: true
        }
    },
    ....
    ....
});
```

The array of numeric phone numbers is not passed for validation.

**Input**: `[ '9252522525', '9252525555' ]`

**Error**:

```
{ [SequelizeValidationError: Validation error]
  name: 'SequelizeValidationError',
  message: 'Validation error',
  errors: 
   [ { message: 'Validation isNumeric failed',
       type: 'Validation error',
       path: 'phone',
       value: 'Validation isNumeric failed',
       __raw: 'Validation isNumeric failed' } ] }
```

However, the single-value array input `[ '9252522525' ]` is successful. Is it Sequelize's bug or what am I wrong?

### [Edit]

I changed the validator to `is`, but no success.

```
validate: {
    is: ["^[0-9]+$", "i"]
}
```

I got the following error.

```
{ [SequelizeValidationError: Validation error]
  name: 'SequelizeValidationError',
  message: 'Validation error',
  errors: 
   [ { message: 'Validation is failed',
       type: 'Validation error',
       path: 'phone',
       value: 'Validation is failed',
       __raw: 'Validation is failed' } ] }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the Sequelize github repo issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3208), all of the validators apply to the array, not to the individual item of the array that seems unclear to me as an end user. The workaround is to define custom validator:

```
phone: {
    type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING),
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
        isValidPhoneNo: function(value) {
            if (!value) return value;

            var regexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
            var values = (Array.isArray(value)) ? value : [value];

            values.forEach(function(val) {
                if (!regexp.test(val)) {
                    throw new Error("Number only is allowed.");
                }
            });
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think because type of `phone` is `ARRAY`, not `STRING`.
`isNumeric` can't be applied for `phone`, I think.